# Cannot RDP to one, of two, VMs on Azure

Tags: azure

I have two VMs configured on Azure. One I can RDP to, no problems at all, the other I get a message stating:
"The Mac cannot connect to the Windows-based computer…" - this is on my iMac - but I also cannot RDP into that VM from a Vista system and a Windows Server 2008.

The only difference between the two VMs is that the one I CAN connect to has an "RDP Certificate Thumbprint" and the other does not.

The one with no certificate - was working fine a couple of weeks ago. No changes were made. Endpoints are good. I've rebooted, restarted, and nothing makes a difference.

I'm assuming it has something to do with not having that RDP Certificate Thumbprint - but I've never created, downloaded, uploaded a certificate in the first place so I'm not sure.

Any thoughts?

Thanks for any help!
Rob

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is configure Remote Desktop for that Role before you publish the package. While you do that, choose "Automatic"  for the certificate. Here are a few screenshots that might be helpful for you.[image: Here is the option of configuring Remote Desktop of all roles.]

[image: This is what RDP configuration looks like. Choose Automatic as shown in the figure.]